# How Change an HTML link to a mailto link in Wordpress?

Tags: html, hyperlink

There is a short code in which you are to put you link in. I cannot access support for this right now. I was wondering if anyone had the code for a mailto: link? I know this must be a silly question. My brain is off right now

here is the way it's marked up now

```
applylink="http://themeforest.com"
```

Comment: Just change it to a `mailto:` URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applylink="mailto:example@example.com"`

Answer (score 2):

The `mailto` is set up in the link code, so:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">LINK</a>
```

Or you can simply add `mailto:` when you add a link in wp: http://ctrlv.in/291271